# Facets count limit 5 in Azure cognitive search site autogenerated

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

first of all I am not familiar with javascript but I saw the easy way azure search generator offers a portal with search features and I used it to make a search portal for more than 100K files. Everything is fine except that I'm facing the same issue of the limit of 5 facets mentionned in this old post ([Facet count in Azure cognitive search (Automagic)](http://azsearchstore.azurewebsites.net/azsearchgenerator/)). Using search explorer I can see the request url needed (example : facet=category,count:10 / https://xxxxxsearch.search.windows.net/indexes/azureblob-index/docs?api-version=2020-06-30-Preview&search=*&facet=category%2Ccount%3A10) but can't figure out where to put this in search app hmtl page or how I can parse it to automagic to consider this.

thank you Gaurav for your feedback. no, that part is clear for me. Please let me show an example of what  I want to achieve.I generated a search a portal using [AzSearchGenerator](http://azsearchstore.azurewebsites.net/azsearchgenerator/) and for this sample I have 7 files with the same metadata key but with 7 differents values ([blob-content-files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uLmgU.png)). I am seeking a way to override the limit of 5 checkboxfacets in the search portal generated (check here : [portal-search-generated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vO2mX.png)). Is there a way to change this by including the request url with count parameter higher than 5 checkboxes ([storage-explorer-request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JPQ3r.png) ) to update the automagic instance in the html code ([automagic-intialization-html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vhyki.png)).

Could you please advice me how I can complete this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found which parameter to update. In the AzSearch.bundle.js referenced in in the html page (see printscreen [parameter to change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/naz6K.png)), the default value is at line 44 on the checkboxfacet part. I just updated it with the right value, in my case I put count:30 and now I have more than 5 items in the checkboxes.
[Result after change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XRbqH.png)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you're looking for a way to specify `facet` parameter in Search Explorer in Azure Portal.

Simply add `&facet=category,count:10` in the Query string field and that should do the trick. For example, see the screenshot below.

[image]